# Spring-boot error starting tomcat context. Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar'

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am new to spring-boot. So after bootstrapping a project from spring initializr, I was trying to run it on intellij. But I am getting error while starting it.

Following are the **versions**:
Java : 8
Spring-boot: 2.0.6
I have tried changing the spring boot version but it didn't help.
Also changed the server port in application.properties but that also didn't help.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>ghosh.debarshi</groupId>
<artifactId>spring5webapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring5webapp</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**stack trace**:

```
   Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1230)
    at ghosh.debarshi.spring5webapp.Spring5webappApplication.main (Spring5webappApplication.java:10)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize (TomcatWebServer.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init> (TomcatWebServer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1230)
    at ghosh.debarshi.spring5webapp.Spring5webappApplication.main (Spring5webappApplication.java:10)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$83c4f158]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Comment: can you paste application.properties code?

Comment: application.properties is currently empty. No data source has been configured.

Comment: try removing jpa dependency, I hope it will work

Comment: Well, it did. Thanks. Novice mistake.

Comment: I am pasting this as answer, accept that and do upvote. Thanks !

Comment: That error for me gone after removing the jpa dependency , @iamrajshah thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you have not added any database to this project remove `data-jpa` dependencies from your pom.xml file,
It was creating a dependency conflict.
It will run properly once removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either add a database configuration or remove database dependency from porm.xml. Once you add database dependency you need to add configurations like below.

```
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    spring.datasource.username=mysqluser
    spring.datasource.password=mysqlpass
    spring.datasource.url=
    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Two thing you can do to resolve this Issue:

1. Remove the data source dependency from pom.xml.
2. And 2nd one is either you can configure your data source inside application.properties.

like below..

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema
spring.datasource.username=....?
spring.datasource.password=...?
```