# spring boot application unable to run with jdk 11 and tomcat version 9.0.24

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring Boot application unable to run with JDK 11 and tomcat version 9.0.24

> ' Unable to start web server; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class
>   path resource '

**Here is pom.xml file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.eventFlow</groupId>
    <artifactId>EventFlow</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>EventFlow</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <camel-core-version>2.23.0</camel-core-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Exclude Spring Boot's Default Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for SMTP Appender -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for Async Logging with Log4j 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



The following error occurs when start the application
```

below is the exception

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-09-19 13:29:15.501 ERROR DESKTOP-43PHFNJ --- [ main] o.s.b.SpringApplication : Application run failed org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'routeControllerEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/actuate/endpoint/CamelRouteControllerEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'routeControllerEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camelContext' defined in class path resource [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader context: EventFlow delegate: false ----------> Parent Classloader: java.net.URLClassLoader@eec5a4a ] at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'routeControllerEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/actuate/endpoint/CamelRouteControllerEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'routeControllerEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camelContext' defined in class path resource [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader context: EventFlow delegate: false ----------> Parent Classloader: java.net.URLClassLoader@eec5a4a ] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:202) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ... 49 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'routeControllerEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/actuate/endpoint/CamelRouteControllerEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'routeControllerEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camelContext' defined in class path resource [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader context: EventFlow delegate: false ----------> Parent Classloader: java.net.URLClassLoader@eec5a4a ] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ... 66 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'routeControllerEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/actuate/endpoint/CamelRouteControllerEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'routeControllerEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camelContext' defined in class path resource [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader context: EventFlow delegate: false ----------> Parent Classloader: java.net.URLClassLoader@eec5a4a ] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBean(EndpointDiscoverer.java:141) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBeans(EndpointDiscoverer.java:131) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:120) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:114) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:72) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4e33dbcc.CGLIB$servletEndpointRegistrar$0() at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4e33dbcc$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4ca9b4f2.invoke() at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4e33dbcc.servletEndpointRegistrar() at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ... 67 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camelContext' defined in class path resource [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader context: EventFlow
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring-boot error starting tomcat context. Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721530/spring-boot-error-starting-tomcat-context-error-creating-bean-with-name-servle)

Comment: thanks issue solved with updating camel core version to 3.0.0-M1, for jdk 11